How to embed multiple molecules with rdkit?
I am new to rdkit and struggle with something I thought would be simple: I want to randomly embed two molecules in 3D space so that the two do not overlap. This is to generate an initial state for molecular dynamics simulations. I attempted this with AllChem.EmbedMolecule:
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
import py3Dmol

m1 = Chem.MolFromSmiles(r"[O-]P(=O)([O-])OC[C@@H]4[C@H](C[C@H](N1C=CC(N)=NC(=O)1)O4)O")
m1 = Chem.AddHs(m1)
m2 = Chem.MolFromSmiles(r"[O-]P(=O)([O-])OC[C@@H]4[C@H](C[C@H](N9C=NC5C(=O)NC(N)=NC=59)O4)O")
m2 = Chem.AddHs(m2)

AllChem.EmbedMolecule(m1, useRandomCoords=True)
AllChem.EmbedMolecule(m2, useRandomCoords=True)

# visualizing the embedding
p = py3Dmol.view(width=1200,height=800)
p.addModel(Chem.MolToMolBlock(m1), 'sdf')
p.addModel(Chem.MolToMolBlock(m2), 'sdf')
p.setStyle({'stick':{}})
p.zoomTo()
p.show()

However, this places the two molecules right on-top ot each other:

I also found Pharm3D.EmbedLib.EmbedMol which accepts an excludedVolumes argument. I was thinking to iteratively embed each molecule, compute its volume and add to the list of excluded volumes for the next embedding. Unfortunately, I cannot find out how to obtain the required ExcludedVolume objects for the embedded molecules. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If each molecule is independently defined by its SMILES string, mark them as components by the non-bonding .  This is an old way to describe for instance co-crystals such as hydrates like $\ce{CuSO4 * 5 H2O}$ as
O.O.O.O.O.[O-]S(=O)(=O)[O-].[Cu+2]

(PubChem).  Consider the tutorial by Daylight as one entry to familiarize yourself with the syntax of SMILES and SMARTS in addition to the article on Wikipedia.
Departing from the two individual strings m1 and m2, the Python moderated concatenation then could run by
...
m1 = (r"[O-]P(=O)([O-])OC[C@@H]4[C@H](C[C@H](N1C=CC(N)=NC(=O)1)O4)O")
m2 = (r"[O-]P(=O)([O-])OC[C@@H]4[C@H](C[C@H](N9C=NC5C(=O)NC(N)=NC=59)O4)O")

mixture = ".".join([m1, m2])
...


Thank you for the answer. This works. I was originally hesitant to use this method as my molecules feature aromatic rings and I was worried that the simulaneous embedding you suggest could create interlocked rings among the two DNA strands. However, if this is the case, it could just as well occur for a single DNA strand already. I presume that RDKit has clever means to avoid this and will go for the suggested solution.
